# internet explorer vs highstock scrollbar

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, highcharts

I´m building a web application using rails with a bunch of plugins including highcharts and highstock.

The problem: The highstock [basic chart](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/) doesn't display it's horizontal scrollbar (the hole bar) in IE browser.

I tried:

- Explicitly call `scrollbar: { enabled: true }`
- Dealing with the `.ui-widget :active { outline: none; }` as it´s a solution in a google search and I am using jqueryUI as well.

Any more thoughs or similar trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a false question, and for this I am sorry.

The problem, which at first I didn´t really think it was possible, was in the UTC date format in the data.

I was formatting the dates using `new Date(Date.parse(value.replace(/-/g, " ")));` as I saw in some blog and then passing it to UTC. In chrome all was ok but IE was picky.

After all this converting with just `new Date(value)` was sufficient.

Anyhow, be aware that this error didn't show up until I messed around the F12 tools in IE (that are really inferior to chrome I might add) and found the returned json had `NaN` in UTC dates.